# Dynamic buttons to modify objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object, button, dynamic

So, I have a div(D1) that is populated dynamically from the fields of an object declared in a different div(D2). So is it possible to have a dynamically created button in D1 that will modify the grading area object in D1.
Object in D2:

```
var grades = new Array("88", "91", "75", "96");
var area1 = new GradingArea("Homework", 30, grades);
var area2 = new GradingArea("Classwork", 40, grades);
var gradingareas = new Array(area1, area2);

var course1 = new Course("CS1500", gradingareas, 85);
```

Populating in D1 is done by a function where the passed argument in maincourse and there is a for loop that basically is toString for the grades and at the end will modify the HTML of D1 to include:

```
    function bringforward(maincourse){
    for(var i = 0;i<maincourse.gradingareas.length; i++){
     txt = "Accumulatedgrades" +"<button onclick=AddGrade(maincourse.gradingareas[i]);>" + "Add Grade" + "</button>"
    }
document.getElementById("currentclassareas").innerHTML=txt; //current class areas is a paragraph tag
    }
```

Accumulated grades is just a placeholder and represents a string computed elsewhere

AddGrade calls a alert box to enter a new value to add to the array in the maincourse object with a push.  But I always get that "maincourse.gradingareas[i] is not defined" because I assume it doesn't keep it with the written statement within the div.  I have tried using addElement(button) and wrapping AddGrade with just a function and neither has been successful.  Any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: Actually, Javascript can be very much object oriented...
I don't understand which part of your code is "the object in D1". Is it course1? area1? or what? What is it exactly you're trying to achieve? Please make your question clearer.

Comment: "I am new to javascript and I know it is not really object oriented"
Actually, almost everything is an object in JavaScript, including functions. Only the primitive types aren't, but they have object wrappers that allows to treat them as objects.

For instance, you can do `'my string'.length` even tough a string is a primitive type.

Maybe someone else will understand, but it's unclear to me what you are trying to achieve? We can't even see the definition of the `maincourse` object in your code, is this a global variable? Is the `i` variable declared globally as well?

Comment: There is a function that you pass a course to that will populate D1 and maincourse is the passed argument.  i is part of a for loop so that it will print all the grading area objects to D1.  I added some clarifications and code